# How to create and use vapi files?

Tags: vala, vapi

I want to make a custom vapi file, I have the basic stuff but I obviously miss something and I can't find anywhere how to do this properly. My main goal is to create a torrent app, using [libtorrent](http://www.libtorrent.org/), and create the GUI (the frontend?) with vala and gtk.

I have a `c_func_head.h`:

```
#ifndef WHATEVER_H_INCLUDED
#define WHATEVER_H_INCLUDED
int add(int a, int b);
#endif
```

`c_functions.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "c_func_head.h"

int add(int a, int b){
  printf("Adding numbers in c...\n");
  return a+b;
}
```

`vala_p.vapi`:

```
[CCode (cheader_filename = "c_func_head.h")]
namespace MyFunc {
    [CCode (cname = "add")]
    public int add (int a, int b);
}
```

and finally `vala_program.vala`:

```
//extern int add(int a, int b);
using MyFunc;

void main(){
    stdout.printf("Calling a c function...\n");
    //stdout.printf("The sum is: %d\n", add2number(2, 2));
    int sum = add(2, 2);
    stdout.printf("The sum is: %d\n", sum);
}
```

As you can see I used an extern too, it worked with it but I want to use vapi files.

I compiled with (everything is in the same folder):

```
valac vala_program.vala --vapidir=vala_p.vapi -o mustrun
```

and the error is:

```
The namespace name `MyFunc' could not be found using MyFunc;
```

One more thing. Is it possible to make bindings for libtorrent? It uses C++ and I guess I have to use C++ too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't make Vala bindings of C++ code. Only C. There a [a guide to writing legacy bindings](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/LegacyBindings) and [a binding for Transmission](https://github.com/apmasell/vapis/blob/master/transmission-2.0.vapi), which is C-based.

As for the specific error you have, you want to call `valac vala_program.vala vala_p.vapi` if the library (i.e., header files) are the the same directory or `valac vala_program.vala --pkg vala_p --vapidir=/path/to/directory/containing/vapi`.

Comment: When I compiled with the first I got undefined reference to 'add' function.
The second method says that it cannot find the "c_func_head.h" file. (I created an .o file too but no luck)

Comment: In the first, you still have to provide the C code. You can do `valac vala_program.vala vala_p.vapi c_functions.c` if it is raw source that you want included. If not, use `-X` to give the right arguments to the C compiler to link against your code. For the second, the C compiler doesn't know where to search for headers; try passing `-X -I.` to include the current directory.